# Check the second checkbox of a table row

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a table tr with two checkboxes and I would like to check the second ckeckbox.

This code checks both checkboxex :

```
var tr = $("tr:has(td:contains("+v_id+"))[id*='select_pharmacien']");
    tr.find("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked','checked');
```

Is it possible to add [1] to indicate that I want the second checkbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
tr.find("input[type='checkbox']").eq(1).prop('checked',true)
```